# How to disable wipe my phone option on ADM for me and for anyone else who have access to my account

Tags: 8.1-oreo, android-device-manager

So, I recently recalled how my account was compromised years ago, and the hacker proceeded to delete two of my old devices. It was frustrating because not only was my account gone, but so was all of my data on my phone. I'm sure it has something to do with Google's ADM service. I looked through the options and discovered the toggle to keep the device from being deleted.

Now that I've remembered the incident, I'm becoming quite paranoid since I don't want to lose all of my data again without notice. So I went back up to the toggle and looked for it again, but there was nothing there. I looked on Google for a solution and the only one I found was to either delete my Google account or disable ADM for all of my accounts, which would be awful if I forgot where I put my phone.

I've already gone through my settings and discovered that disabling ADM's admin privilege prevents it from erasing my phone, though I'm not sure if it works or not because I obviously don't want to test it out.

Is there a way to merely disable the wiping and keep the rest? Is disabling ADM's admin privileges sufficient?

To avoid being hacked, I know I can safeguard my accounts using 2FA and strong passwords (which I have already done). However, mistakes do happen, and I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I dont like asking Google to help me remember anything, but I still find myself using their oh so accessible tools. However, ADM is completely unnecessry. Your phone's settings should have the ability to help find it already present. As for backing up your data, there are a number of alternatives available. You could even back it up to your own pc if you like: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-backup-android-phone-to-pc-4769775&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiysd7HmIb3AhUHSjABHe3CBt0QFXoECAoQAg&usg=AOvVaw2rWroggBCcCt4El2ucjDn4. You just have to decide what feels right for you.

Unless you are a programmer well-versed in cyber security, you're going to have to rely on someone else to do the heavy lifting. It really just comes down to trusting whatever source you choose.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It provides an alternative to ADM, which in effect nullifies the question since ADM is then unnecessary.

Comment: so how can OP find device if ADM is disabled completely?

Comment: As stated in my initial response, most phones, mine included have the ability to assist location of said device, without utilizing Googles ADM, which was the service in question. Does your phone have location assistance natively? I'm not a guru, and am new to all of this, so if u know something better plz just come out and say it. I abhor being toyed with. If I misunderstood your position or motivation, I apologize.

Comment: no need to apologize :) but please give example for *"location assistance natively"* so others can learn from your answer - without any instruction it's hard to follow you. (personally my phone is running google's android with google's ADM location assistance "natively", but that doesn't matter)